# How can I start measurement of Heart Rate sensor in a specific device NO1 D5. runs Android 4.4

Tags: android, sensormanager

D5 runs Android 4.4

I want to measure the heart rate, but standard way of registerListener is not working (not hardware problem, with inbuilt app is working).

I get all sensors from device and i found this:

```
{Sensor name="ULPSH Heart Rate M", vendor="QuickLogic Inc", version=1, type=87, maxRange=100.0, resolution=1.0, power=1.1, minDelay=0}
```

In android.hardware.Sensor i don't found this type id 87 so i tried the following:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mHeartRate = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(87);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRate, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

....

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == 87) {
        //do something 
    }
}
```

but unfortunately is not working, the measurement is not getting started.

I tried this code with another sensor (Step Counter, type 19) that works well.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I think the problem is the firmware. You also can't get access to gyro, barometer and etc.

I found in the Launcher app how you can access the last heart rate.

```
System.getInt(getContentResolver(), "last_heart_rate", 0);
```